# OpenCV: Contextual image classification

Tags: opencv, classification

I'm currently trying to implement some kind of basic pattern recognition for understanding whether parts of a building are a wall, a roof,a window etc.

Thanks to Sonka et al, I've been able to create with a GLCM in a fixed 10*10 window a 6 feature *4 direction feature vector for parts of the image. I'm now looking how to go from pixels with feature descriptions to describing areas as described above. An attractive proposition is to use [contextual image classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contextual_image_classification). However, I'm unclear what is meant exactly by two in terms of the algorithm stated:

> Calculate the parameters of probability distribution p (E | Ws ) and P ( Ws )

I'm confused by what this means exactly, and how to go around it. If we take this example of a building :

[image: painted building]

1) Will this mean that for each pixel within the yellow, red or blue boundaries (which should be shaded in, yes) the probability of (E|Ws) is 1, and that the probability only changes around the edges.

2) Is determining these probabilities equivalent to creation of a symmetrical, normalised GLCM but with labels instead of pixel values ?.

3) Can it be used to describe regions (wall,window,roof), as suggested by the above image?.

Many thanks,

P.L.G.

**Referencing:**

Sonka, M. Hvlac, V. Boyle, R. (2008). Image processing, Analysis and machine vision.